# Installation of Compatible version of Numpy and Scipy on Abaqus 6.13-2 with python 2.6.2

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Can anyone give inputs/clue/direction on installation of compatible version of numpy and scipy in abaqus python 2.6.2?
I tried installing numpy-1.6.2, numpy-1.7.1  and numpy-1.8.1. But all gives an error of unable to find vcvarsall.bat. because it doesn't have a module named msvccomplier. based on the some of the answers, I verified the visual studio version and it is 2008.

Could anyone please give direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is: install python 2.6.2 separately onto your system (it looks like you are using windows, right?), and then install scipy corresponding to python 2.6.2, and then copy the site-packages to the abaqus folder.

Note that 1) you can't use matplotlib due to the tkinter problem; 2) the numpy is already coming with abaqus so you don't need to install it by hand.

Comment: I have installed python2.7 into my system and then tried to take the numpy and scipy modules from to abaqus, and it was showing error as it  was linking with python27.dll file? Probably I should uninstall that and install the python 2.6.2. I'll try that..

Comment: Try that - I did it with Python 2.6 with Abaqus 6.12-1, and it worked fine.

Comment: I am facing trouble with installation of Scipy. It is showing BlASNotFoundError. May I know which scipy version you had used for installing?

Comment: Are you using 64 bit Python? In that case, have you been using the package from Christoph Gohlke? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I've used python 2.6 from the scipy offical website. The details of python installed is as follows: Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:46:50) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: My OS is 64-bit Windows 7 Enetrprise

Comment: May I know your inputs in this regard. Thank you

Comment: I think your python version is great! Just that when you install numpy and scipy, use the link that I gave you to install. Try that :)

Comment: I did that, installation was OK. But when I try to open abaqus/abaqus CAE, it shows FATAL error:numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.

Comment: Hmmm... Never seen that before. First of all - I would suggest check the python version that ABAQUS is using to make sure it is correct, as well as the according numpy/scipy versions. Second... have you tried only copy the scipy folder under site-packages, instead of everything? (Because numpy is already included)

Comment: May I know the compatible version of scipy with numpy 1.4.2. Now I've tried to python and install the similar version of numpy into puthon 2.6. Abaqus is working fine, but when I run my script which calls scipy, it shows: DLL load failed:%1 is not a valid win 32 application.

Comment: Sorry that I don't know... Probably this is a good question to open a new thread, or you may ask in the scipy mailing list.